# Change the Y-axis values from real numbers to integers in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I have a chart that I want to include in my website using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). In the Y-axis, it gives me real numbers instead of integers. How can I change the number to integers?

Here's a picture of what I have now:

[image: current chart with real numbers]

And this is the code:

```
var lineChartData = {

    labels : ["2013/04/01","2013/03/31", "2013/03/30", "2013/03/29", "2013/03/28","2013/03/27", "2013/03/26"],

    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : ["0", "2","1", "0", "1","0","1"]
        }
    ]

}

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(lineChartData);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this, where max is the highest value of your data.

```
var steps = 3;
new Chart(ctx).Bar(plotData, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: steps,
    scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(max / steps),
    scaleStartValue: 0
});
```

Comment: @Mewel I don't wan't the y-axis labels to be displayed at all. How could I do that? There has to be an option right.

Comment: I found it. If anyone wants to remove the labels entirely you can add `scaleShowLabels: false` to your `option` attribute.

Answer (score 163):

I handled it this way in new version:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0) {return value;}}
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Worked like a charm. I wonder why this isn't the top answer.

Comment: This is a great answer. It's worth noting that the same can be done with the [tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback)

Comment: I'd like to suggest this code as solution. That works perfectly!

Comment: Those facing type issues. Rename "yAxes" to "y" and it should be an object not an array.

Comment: Thanks. beginAtZero: true is what I needed.

Answer (score 61):

I wasn't able to get the existing answers to work for me when using the new **version 2 of Chart.js**, so here's what I found to solve this problem in V2:

```
new Chart(ctx, {type: 'bar', data: barChartData,
  options:{ 
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: please be aware that this will show all integers in your y-axis. if your graph is running from 0 to 300, all the 301 integers and grid lines will be shown.

Comment: @apfz Very true, this only works well when you have a good idea of your data's scale, and can work out a reasonable step size in advance.

Comment: Set stepSize: 1 -> work perfectly on v3.8.0, keep in mind i have this doubt : autoSkip: false, // false -> show all labels (not reduced by Chart.js)
but ... stepSize : 1, // ignored if autoSkip == true ?

Answer (score 54):

I know this is an old question now, but in the current version (v2.9.3) you can just set the precision of the y-axis ticks to zero to get integers:

```
options: {  
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                precision: 0
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as this needs no additional considerations (finding the maximum, declaring steps, etc.)

Comment: This shows a compilation error when using typescript, the property don't seems to be declared.

Comment: Also just used this and it seemed to be the right way to go for those finding this post later. (not using typescript though so i cannot comment on that)

Answer (score 20):

As Ben Bloodworth above mentioned, the easier way is adding in options (precision: 0).

Currently working fine in version 3.7.1

```
 options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        precision: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

Check the [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) documentation, in the Global configuration section:

> // Boolean - Whether the scale should stick to integers, not floats even if drawing space is there
>       **scaleIntegersOnly: true,**

Comment: If it doesn't work you probably didn't have `scaleOverride: true`.

Comment: Probably chart version 1, that's outdated

Answer (score 7):

If you like to start in a different number than zero, you have to take that into account:

```
var step  = 5;
var max   = 90
var start = 40;
new Chart(income).Bar(barData, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max-start)/step),
    scaleStepWidth: step,
    scaleStartValue: start
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Something to note,
There are different versions of Chart.js, and they have different options object. In versions 3 and above, the x and y axis is an object whereas, in versions less than 3, they are defined as an array.
Example,
For version 3 and above,

```
 options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    precision: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For version 3 and below,

```
options: {  
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                precision: 0
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Also, note that the `y` and `x` becomes `yAxes` and `xAxex` respectively.

Comment: Thanks!  For v4.4.0 your top example works great!

Comment: Worked with v4.4.1 line chart.