# How to display only integers in javascript chart.js

Tags: javascript

I want to display only integers not floats in the chart created by java script library [chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

Here is the link to the example [graph](http://qlu.in/0o3CTx/stats/)

I am new to this Can someone help me to configure this

Comment: JSFiddle would help immensely...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751571/how-to-change-the-y-axis-values-from-real-numbers-to-integer-in-chartjs

Comment: Just replace your chart.js code with code on this `http://jsfiddle.net/Ase7V/` and you are good to go

Answer (score 36):

This is the way to do it using chart.js 2.5 :
Just add this callback function to the yAxes ticks property

function (value) { if (Number.isInteger(value)) { return value; } }

or just use stepSize: 1 in the same place.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alelase/6f8wrz03/2/

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart1");
 var data = {
        labels: ['John', 'Alex', 'Walter', 'James', 'Andrew', 'July'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label:  "Messages: ",
                data: [1, 2 , 5, 4, 3, 6],
                backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ]
            }]
    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        beginAtZero: true,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Chart.js bar Chart'
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (value) { if (Number.isInteger(value)) { return value; } },
                        stepSize: 1
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: What about version 2.6? They seem to have changed the way callbacks work.

Comment: As of now, their last version is 2.7. I have tested the stepSize and the callback function for yAxes and they both work ok. In relation to this, they have deprectated the unitStepSize, however the stepSize still works, though. https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases

Answer (score 33):

As of version 2.8, you can simply add the `precision` property of the ticks object as :

```js
yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            precision: 0,
          },
        },
      ],
```

Answer (score 7):

Quik answer for those like me:

```
   ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0) {return value;}}
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var max= 100 //heighest value of your data
var step = 5;// According to your requirement
new Chart(ctx).Bar(plotData, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: step,
    scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(max / step),
    scaleStartValue: 0
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From your example page: http://qlu.in/0o3CTx/stats/

Change:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,{});
```

To:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,{
    scaleOverride: true, 
    scaleStepWidth: 1, 
    scaleSteps: 10
});
```

These options can be found here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#lineChart-chartOptions

You have to specify all three parameters: `scaleOverride`, `scaleStepWidth` and `scaleSteps`

Comment: This actually helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chart.js v4.4.0 and none of the above solutions worked.  (I'm trying to display only whole numbers on the x-axis.)  The following **did** work:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
```