# Limit Chart.js scale to whole numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart

is there a way to limit chart.js scale to single numbers?... The below data can only be whole numbers so there is no point showing to decimal places.

[image]

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695382/how-to-display-only-integers-in-javascript-chart-js

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this problem myself, almost all of the answers I found were attempting to force the step size to 1, which is only a valid option when your dataset is within a small known range. When your dataset can theoretically go from 1 to infinity it will cause all sorts of issues.

```
// vals is an array of your Y axis data
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        maxTicksLimit: Math.min(11, 1 + Math.max.apply(null, vals))
    }
}]
```

This sets the number of ticks to your dataset, or 11 (whichever is less). Credit goes to the original author [@mkucej here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1937#issuecomment-233682999%20here)

Comment: Excellent! This is some great stuff.