# chartjs : how to set custom scale in bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chartjs is a pretty excellent open source tool, but had a quick question about a bar chart I'm trying to create. Given this chart data:

```
    var chartData = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets :[
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                scaleOverride: true,
                scaleSteps: 9,
                data : values
            }
        ]   
    }
```

I had hoped that the chart would draw with top value of 10, whether or not there were any values of 10. I thought the scaleOverride and scaleSteps would accomplish that.

Is it possible to get that output? I went thru the docs and did not see any other obvious options to set.

## Update

got it to work. My orig post did not include the javascript function at the bottom.

```
<div class="barChartTest" id="rating_12229" onload="drawChart();">
<input type="hidden" class="rating-component" comp-name="test1" comp-value="6"/>
<input type="hidden" class="rating-component" comp-name="test2" comp-value="7"/>
<input type="hidden" class="rating-component" comp-name="test3" comp-value="6"/>
<input type="hidden" class="rating-component" comp-name="test4" comp-value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" class="rating-component" comp-name="test5" comp-value="1"/>
</div> 
<canvas id="rating_12229" width="50" height="20"></canvas>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
function buildRatingChartData(ratingId){
    var comps = document.getElementById(ratingId).getElementsByClassName("rating-component");   
    var labels = [];
    var values = [];

    for(var i=0; i<comps.length; i++){

            labels.push(comps[i].getAttribute("comp-name"));
            values.push(comps[i].getAttribute("comp-value"));
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets :[
            {
                scale: 10,
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                scaleOverride:true,
                scaleSteps:9,
                scaleStartValue:0,
                scaleStepWidth:1,
                data : values
            }
        ]   
    }

    return chartData;

}
```

here was where I added those options and got the output I wanted:

```
function drawCharts(){
    var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName("brewRatingData");
    for(var i=0; i<ratings.length; i++){

        var ratingId = ratings[i].getAttribute("id");   
        var canvasId = ratingId.replace("brewRating", "coffeeBarChart");

      var brewChartData = buildRatingChartData(ratingId);
      var ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext("2d");
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(brewChartData, {
        responsive : true,
            scaleOverride:true,
            scaleSteps:10,
            scaleStartValue:0,
            scaleStepWidth:1,
      });   

    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept zedfoxus's answer if it answers your question (which it really seems to)!

Comment: I meant to, but I need to try to re-create the problem and then update the html...will try to do that later tonight

Comment: @brendan, please see updated html/javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Also include `scaleStartValue` and `scaleStepWidth` as stated in [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration).

**Example**

This example creates a bar chart with Y-axis starting at 0 and ending at 900. To do that, step width is set to 100 and number of steps are set to 9.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="income" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var barData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "#48A497",
            strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
            data : [456,479,324,569,702,600]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(73,188,170,0.4)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(72,174,209,0.4)",
            data : [364,504,605,400,345,320]
        }

    ]
};

var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");

new Chart(income).Bar(barData, {
  animation:false,
  scaleOverride:true,
  scaleSteps:9,
  scaleStartValue:0,
  scaleStepWidth:100
});
```

Comment: added those values, but still getting same output

Comment: Can you update your question with your HTML, and output of `values` variable? If we have the data you're using, we can offer a solution faster

Comment: The docs don't explain this very well at all. Thanks for the answer, solved an issue for me!

Comment: great answer.. perfectly worked for me after lot of search

Answer (score 12):

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data:data,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                steps: 10,
                                stepValue: 6,
                                max: 60 //max value for the chart is 60
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: in new version of chartjs v6.4. it is **stepSize** instead of **stepValue**.

Answer (score 1):

@2.8.0
custom y-axis setup. You only need range min/max and with stepSize you control the axis.

```
...
yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 0.1,
            min: 2,
            max: 2.5
            },
        gridLines: {
            display: false 
            },
        stacked: false
                    }]
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle with react-chartjs-2:

Example that starts from 0, makes 2 `steps` each of `size` 20 and goes up to `max`

```js
let options = {
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        steps: 2,
        stepSize: 20,
        max: 40
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
// ... your component structure
return <Line options={options} />
```