# Chart.js - Define custom y-axis scale

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I am working with Chart.js on Asp.Net and I have a bar chart. My dataset has not very close numbers so I can not determine any fixed stepSize for this dataset. 
My dataset like that;
[105000,200000,310000,0.0002]

So, y-axis range seems like that *[0 - 100000 - 200000 - 300000 ...]* but I want to show it like that *[ 0 - **0.005** - 100000 - 200000 - 300000 ...]*.

My chart options :

```
options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                responsive: true,
                mainAspectRatio: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried to add to options "**suggestedMin: 0.005**" but y-axis values didn't change.

How can I define custom scale for y-axis?

Comment: Take a look for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632967/chartjs-how-to-set-custom-scale-in-bar-chart), probably you need to provide `scaleSteps` property or others related to y-axis scaling.

Comment: I already read this but scaleSteps property provide us show y-axis with equal range. I don't want that. There are too small numbers and too large numbers on my dataset so I want to determine the values in the y axis. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `callback` property:

```
options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                responsive: true,
                mainAspectRatio: false,
                callback: (v) => !!~[0, 0.005, 100000, 200000, 300000].indexOf(v) ? v : '',
                min: 0,
                max: 300000,
                step: 0.005
            }
        }]
    }
}
```